# Radius of Gyration Calculation of a Sphere

Tags: calculus, spherical-trigonometry

When viewing the radius of gyration of a sphere, and trying to verify my own calculations $R_g^2=\frac25R^2$ against the [online material](https://www.ncnr.nist.gov/staff/hammouda/distance_learning/chapter_26.pdf) , while the later shows $R_g^2=\frac35R^2$ and does not use the squared moment arm $r\sin\theta$ if rotating about $z-$axis.

**EDIT**

The derivation should br trivial in spherical coordinate system with the volume element $\mathrm{d}V=r^2\sin\theta\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\varphi$. The moment arm shall be $r\sin\theta$. Assuming that the sphere is homogeneous in density ($\rho$ is constant), therefore, the square of the radius of gyration about the axis through the sphere center is expressed as the moment of inertia divided by the mass, i.e.,
\begin{align}
R_g^2&=\frac{\rho\int_0^Rr\mathrm{d}r\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_0^{\pi}r\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta(r\sin\theta)^2}{\rho\frac43\pi R^3}\\
&=\frac{2\pi\frac{R^5}{5}\frac43}{\frac43\pi R^3}\\
&=\frac25 R^2.
\end{align}

where $\frac43$ in the nominator is from $\int\sin^3(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{\cos3\theta}{12} - \frac{3\cos\theta}{4} + c$.

*Requested from Comments that I should present my own calculations.*

I checked [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) which shows that "Solid sphere (ball) of radius r and mass m" has exactly $\frac25R^2$. I was puzzled and wondered to write to the author, but no contact information can be found. What tricks are hidden inside his derivation or some common definition rule I am not aware of?

Comment: Check the URL: if you delete the stuff after the person's name and go to that webpage, it will be the author's homepage.

Comment: If you show us your calculations, we may be able to find an error if there is one. Without your calculations, it's quite impossible to help you out.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate it without cross-sections?

Answer (score 0):

I just have gone through this problem of 2/5 vs 3/5 (taking a polymers class as a physicist) and just figured out the issue we were both having. The typical definition of radius of gyration is with respect to an axis of rotation, and not the center of mass. However, in polymer physics, their radius of gyration is with respect to the center of mass; mathematically (r sin(theta))^2 -> r^2 in our integral. The factor that the theta integral changes from 4/3 to 2, so we can convert our original result by dividing by (4/3) and multiplying, i.e. multiply by the ratio 3/2, so 2/5 becomes 3/5.
I haven't discovered WHY they decided to use this definition or read much info at all about justifying this definition. It's kind of bad/disappointing that this is waved over by everything I find online.